# Por que conjuntos com intervalos de A-z retorna símbolos em REGEX?

Tags: regex

## Cenário:

```js
const texto = 'ABC [abc] a-c 1234';

console.log(texto.match(/[A-z]/g))
```

- Por que o conjunto de `A(maiúsculo)` até `z(minusculo)`, ou seja,
  `/[A-z]/g` me retornou a `[` e `]`?
- O resultado não deveria ser: `[A, B, C, a, b, c, a, c]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[A-z]` irá casar caracteres ASCII na sequência de `A` a `z`. Se você olhar a **[tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)** abaixo verá que existem diversos outros caracteres entre `A` e `z` (incluindo-se aí os colchetes `[]` que você não quer).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você deseja casar apenas letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, de `A` a `Z` e de `a` a `z`, o correto seria usar `[a-zA-Z]`.

```js
const texto = 'ABC [abc] a-c 1234';
console.log(texto.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g))
```

Answer (score 5):

O *range* ou *intervalos* seguem a tabela  [***Unicode***](https://unicode-table.com/pt/).

Eu defini que o meu conjunto deveria ser de `A(maiúsculo) até z(minusculo)`, existem símbolos no meio desse intervalo.
São eles: ***[ \ ] ^ _ `***

Vejam na tabela Unicode:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Nota:

> Os primeiros 127 caracteres da tabela Unicode são os mesmos da tabela
> ASCII